# How to add footer links in Open Cart?

Tags: opencart2.x

I have already added the li tag in footer using Open Cart. However, I am unable to link the page using Open Cart.

For example: I have added li tag as About Us and About Us is also the name of my page. I need to link this page with the li in footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to footer links to your custom information page ex. (About us etc. ).

> Go to Admin Dashboard -> Catalog -> Informations

Here,  you can add your own custom static page.

If you want to link this page on footer. Edit page and check **Bottom** option under Data tab.

[image]